# How can I create a reminder in Netbeans which can be edited by the user?

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a reminder displayed like a sticky note in my system. My initial idea was to have a text area that could be updated using a saved .txt file (which was a bad idea, so I cannot show you the code). 
I want my reminder to be saved even after the user logs out of the system. What can you suggest?
Thank you.
PS. If I didn't explain it clear enough please let me know.

Here's the text area that can be edited when the user wants to have reminders like notes in the system.

[image]

EDIT: I'm merely a beginner in Netbeans, so I've this code:

```
try {
////    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\cqm005\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MASYhista\\ReminderText.txt"));
//    String text = null;
//
//    // repeat until all lines is read
//    while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//        contents.append(text)
//            .append(System.getProperty(
//                "line.separator"));
//    }
//} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
//    e1.printStackTrace();
//} catch (IOException e1) {
//    e1.printStackTrace();
//} finally {
//    try {
//        if (reader != null) {
//            reader.close();
//        }
//    } catch (IOException e1) {
//        e1.printStackTrace();
//    }
//}
//ReminderEditText.setText(contents.toString());
```

-for retrieving data from the .txt file

and I just use

```
       outStream.print(ReminderEditText.getText());

                    outStream.close();
                    RefreshReminder();
```

for saving reminders but it does not work as I expect it to. Please help me.

Comment: *"My initial idea was to have a text area that could be updated using a saved .txt file (which was a bad idea,.."* I just coded a small [task list / reminder app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xaxE.png) that saves tasks to a text file. It's pretty easy and convenient. So I disagree with it being a bad idea. Why do you think it is?. *"..so I cannot show you the code)."* Oh go on.. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: There's something wrong with my code, when I refresh my reminders, or save a new one, after closing the program the data goes back to what it originally was.

Comment: *"There's something wrong with my code,"* I did not advise to post 'code' or (mostly commented out) uncompilable code snippets. I advised to post an MCVE or SSCCE (which are essentially the same thing). Follow the links, read about the form of code I suggested. Voting to close.

Comment: `after closing the program the data goes back to what it originally` - did you read the links provided. You did not post an `MCVE / SSCCE`. The code you posted doesn't compile. You show where you write the file, but not where you read the file.

Answer (score 2):

To save/restore data from a text file into a text area you do something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

class TextAreaLoad extends JPanel
{
    private JTextArea edit;

    public TextAreaLoad()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        edit = new JTextArea(30, 60);
        add(new JScrollPane(edit), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton read = new JButton("Read TextAreaLoad.txt");
        read.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader( "TextAreaLoad.txt" );
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    edit.read( br, null );
                    br.close();
                    edit.requestFocus();
                }
                catch(Exception e2) { System.out.println(e2); }
            }
        });

        add(read, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        JButton write = new JButton("Write TextAreaLoad.txt");
        write.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter( "TextAreaLoad.txt" );
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( writer );
                    edit.write( bw );
                    bw.close();
                    edit.setText("");
                    edit.requestFocus();
                }
                catch(Exception e2) { System.out.println(e2); }
            }
        });

        add(write, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextArea Load");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TextAreaLoad());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But can it be this way: What text I'll write would replace the old text saved in that same .txt?

Comment: @AkaneMikazuki, I have no idea what you are asking. I provided working code for you to test. If you still have a problem then post a "Minimal Example" demonstrating the problem as was suggested in the first comment to your question.